# C++ AMP calculations and WPF rendering graphics card dual use performance

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, rendering, c++-amp

*Situation:*

In an application that has both the need for calculation as well as rendering images (image preprocessing and then displaying) I want to use both AMP and WPF (with AMP doing some filters on the images and WPF not doing much more than displaying scaled/rotated images and some simple overlays, both running at roughly 30fps, new images will continuously stream in).

*Question:*

Is there any way to find out how the 2 will influence each other?

I am wondering on whether I will see the hopefully nice speed-up I will see in an isolated AMP only environment in the actual application later on as well.

*Additional Info:*

I will be able and am going to measure the AMP performance separately, since it is low level and new functionality that I am going to set up in a separate project anyway. The WPF rendering part already exists though in a complex application, so it would be difficult to isolate that.

I am not planning on doing the filters etc for rendering only since the results will be needed in intermediate levels as well (other algorithms, e. g. edge detection, saving, ...).

Comment: In what way do you think they will influence each other? After all, both are just instructions getting executed by the cpu.

Comment: I would strongly hope both WPF Rendering and AMP to be executed on the GPU. So they would share GPU resources. (CPU overhead should be mostly limited to memory transfer.)

Comment: GPU is like a specialized CPU. I'm not sure there is a reason it can only do the AMP part but not the WPF part. After all it's capable of displaying your screen and at the same time do AMP, right? Anyway: the only proper way to find out is to just try it. E.g. compile your AMP stuff to a dll, write a small C++/CLI dll that uses it and has a function to start the AMP processing. Call that function from your WPF app.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you should consider here;

> Is there any way to find out how the 2 will influence each other?

Directly no, but indirectly yes. Both WPF and AMP are making use of the GPU for rendering. If the AMP portion of your application uses too much of the GPU's resources it will interfere with your frame rate. The [Cartoonizer case study from the C++ AMP book](http://ampbook.codeplex.com/) uses MFC and C++ AMP to do exactly the way you describe. On slower hardware with high image processing loads you can see the application's responsiveness suffer. However in almost all cases cartoonizing images on the GPU is much faster and can achieve video frame rates.

> I am wondering on whether I will see the hopefully nice speed-up

With any GPU application the key to seeing performance improvements is that the speedup from running compute on the GPU, rather than the CPU, must make up for the additional overhead of copying data to and from the GPU.

In this case there is additional overhead as you must also marshal data from the native (C++ AMP) to managed (WPF) environments. You need to take care to do this efficiently by ensuring that your data types are blitable and do not require explicit marshaling. I implemented an [N-body modeling application](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/nbody/) that used WPF and native code.

Ideally you would want to render the results of the GPU calculation without moving it through the CPU. This is possible but not if you explicitly involve WPF. The N-body example achieves this by embedding a DirectX render area directly into the WPF and then renders data directly from the AMP arrays. This was largely because the WPF viewport3D really didn't meet my performance needs. For rendering images WPF may be fine.

Unless things have changed with VS 2013 you definitely want your C++ AMP code in a separate DLL as there are some limitations when using native code in a C++/CLI project.

As @stijn suggests I would build a small prototype to make sure that the gains you get by moving some of the compute to the GPU are not lost due to the overhead of moving data both to and from the GPU but also into WPF.

Comment: I would add to Ade's answer that theoretically you could have a system with 2 GPUs, where one will be used solely for computation and the other for rendering. In such case the interference will be minimal to none. And on the other end of the spectrum, you can have a system with an integrated GPU, where you can leverage data transfer improvements for such systems in VS 2013 version of C++ AMP.